# How to resume haml parsing after using filter?

Tags: haml

I want to insert some plain html into haml file using `:plain` filter:

```
!!!5
%html
  %head
    :plain
      <!-- Here is some plain HTML --><script src:'#'></script>

  %body
    = haml :_navbar
    %main.container
      =yield
```

But it turns out haml treat the parts after `%body` all plain text, how to solve this?

Comment: Try to skip it using for exp :  \some html codeafter this slash or #{Insert plain html}

Comment: What result are you getting, are you sure you have the indentation right in your source? The code you have given is correct and will generate `body` and `main` elements.